# Modify each instance according to previous

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have an object consisting of a simple edge.
The edge has the first vertex assigned to a vertex group named "first", similarly for the "last":

[image]

The object is distributed (using Instance on Points) on a curve points like this:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to align the "first" vertex of each instance with the "last" vertex of the previous instance, so the result should be like this:

[image]

I thought such task will be very simple, but I tried various approaches without any luck, so any suggestions are highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use Field at Index:

[image]

In this case, index is -3 because your lines are pointed backwards

But if you want to set data only by vertex group, and number of points in each line may be different, you can use setup like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry about having that flipped. Could you please give me a hint how to use "last" attribute for getting the position instead of "substract 3" (after swapping first vs last to make it correct)? I am able to code addons in Python, but these GNodes are just complete scifi to me...

Comment: Already done in second example

Comment: Thank you @Crantisz, you have provided me the solution which I will utilize and extend in my project. I have marked your answer as Accepted :) Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but if you're looking for separate edges threaded along a curve, you can do it directly this way:

[image]

Here I simply convert the curve into a mesh and split the edges.

(To make this more visible, I have scaled the individual edges here).

Comment: Thanks, but I really wanted to do exactly what I described - to "merge" those vertices of particular named attributes, always between 2 neighbor instances. Because later I want to extend this basic functionality to something more complex. But thank you!